# App Branching with Google Analytics 4: code not working correctly

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-analytics, xamarin.android, branch, branch.io

I am a Xamarin developer and I have followed the URL https://help.branch.io/partners-portal/docs/google-analytics-4#properties-sent-to-google-analytics to integrate Google Analytics 4 in Xamarin forms Android which is use to send branch data to Google Analytics 4  dashboard but provided code below is not working correctly, the Branch data is not being sent to the Google Analytics 4 dashboard.

BranchAndroid.GetInstance().SetRequestMetadata("$firebase_app_instance_id", (string) FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this).GetAppInstanceId());